# How to call a component condition at the time of rendering

Tags: angular, dom, angular-ng-if

`my-component` is a reusable component, so while I try to render it in different components I want to test a condition, if it satisfies then only it should render into the DOM.

```
<app1>
<my-component *ngIf="aConditionCheckFromMyComponent"></my-component>
<app1>

<app2>
<my-component *ngIf="aConditionCheckFromMyComponent"></my-component>
<app2>
```

My idea is to create a service and then create another function which return the same condition

```
import my-component
class Utility {

constructor(private mc: my-component) {
}

get anotherConditionFunction(): boolean {
 return mc.aConditionCheckFromMyComponent();
}
```

now I can use: `utilityObj.anotherConditionFunction();`

... but I don't find it proper. Do you have any other ways? How to do this properly?

Comment: Define the condition in the service and call it from multiple components

Comment: That's the only way? No other easy to maintain solution? @T.SunilRao

Comment: Components are not meant to share their controllers content (), you should define your condition in a service that you inject wherever you want to access it.

Comment: It depends on your use case. Please elaborate your use case to optimize solution

Comment: @T.SunilRao, I have a footer bar which should be display based on a condition, now the footer bar is every where (in each component) but only should display if satisfy the condition.

Comment: I don't understand the exact scenario here. Wouldn't the condition either pass or fail on each it's instance if the condition is inside the child component? How do you plan to selectively pass or fail the condition? Does the condition depend on an outside variable?

Comment: @MichaelD, yes condition would pass/fail as per the components. Condition isn't inside the child component, it is inside a service file. It is depends on the values whether a condition will be true/false which is also there in the service file.

Comment: @Hemang The condition logic should be put inside a service or resolver or guard depending on the variables of your condition and the component can use that condition

Comment: @Hemang: Couldn't you then wrap the entire child's template markup in `<ng-container *ngIf="condition"></ng-container>`. It wouldn't lead to additional DOM elements in case the condition fails.

Comment: @MichaelD, ng-container is not stoping rendering the component in DOM. I think, as in the below answer I'll have to add *ngIf as and when applicable.

Answer (score 1):

i had the same problem and i solved it by creating an Injectable class,placing it in app folder and imported it in all components that nead to use global conditions

```
import {Injectable} from '@angular/core';

@Injectable()
export class Globals {

    showSomeComponent = false;
    public constructor() {
        this.showSomeComponent = true;
    }
    public setShowSomeComponent (flag) {
        this.showSomeComponent = flag;
    }
}
```

You can change this flag anywhere in the app and instantly all the components that use it will see this change.

usage example:

```
import {Globals} from '../../globals';
@Component({
    selector: 'app-component-1',
    templateUrl: './component-1.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./component-1.component.sass']
})
export class RavanDataGridComponent implements OnInit {
constructor(private globals: Globals) {
    
}
```

html:

```
<app-module-menu *ngIf="this.globals.showSomeComponent">
        </app-module-menu>
```